# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Error not Resolved

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolkit in my ASP.NET 4.5 Web Project in Visual Studio 2012. I am getting following error on the page where I am using Editor Control.

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException:
>   Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution of my problem , I forget to use AJAX Script Manager in my program. As to use ajax tool in our program first we have to use **ajax script manager** in our program .

Answer (score 1):

As far as this case is concerned check if the assembly containing resources has the default namespace set to the same text (Project->Properties->Default namespace; in VS)